# Was Laban a younger or older brother of Rebekah? (Gen. 29:24)

Tags: genesis, referent-identification

> Rebekah had a brother whose name was Laban

Is there any concrete evidence in the Scripture that shows Laban was either younger or older than his sister Rebekah? Genesis 24:29 and some others don’t specify who was older among these siblings. I’m asking because in some language the way you address a younger/older brother/sister is distinctly different.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Learner123. You may not be aware, if you haven't taken the Tour (bottom l.h.s. link) but questions need to quote in full the Bible verse in question, and also any research you have done to try to get to the bottom of the question. Have you any reason for trying to sort out the right way to address this brother, as the Bible text itself does not seem to attach any importance to this? If the Bible does not say whether Laban was a younger or older brother, why would we today benefit from knowing?

Comment: We are not told so we do not know.

Comment: I added the text of Gen 29:24

Answer (score 2):

Nothing can be discerned from the form of address between Laban and Rebekah, but there are strong clues in the story indicating that Laban acted as adult who spoke for the family.

In Gen. 24, Laban takes the lead in negotiations regarding Rebekah, who is identified as both a "maiden" and "a virgin." When Rebekah runs home to inform her family of Abraham's servant's arrival, it is Laban who goes to the spring to meet him. It is Laban who offers hospitality to the entourage. It is Laban who hears the servant's report concerning his errand to find a wife for Isaac. Crucially, it is Laban who is addressed when the servant declares:

> Now then, if you will deal loyally and truly with my master, tell me;
> and if not, tell me; that I may turn to the right hand or to the left. (v. 49)

Thus the servant treats Laban as an adult who is authorized to speak on behalf of the family. Only after this does Bethuel (Laban and Rebekah's father) enter the narrative and declare together with Laban that the servant may take Rebekah to be Isaac's wife.

> Then Laban and Bethu′el answered, “The thing comes from the Lord; we
> cannot speak to you bad or good. 51 Behold, Rebekah is before you,
> take her and go, and let her be the wife of your master’s son, as the
> Lord has spoken.”

**Conclusion**: In this story, Laban has substantial authority as Betheul's apparently adult son. Therefore, given Rebekah's status as both a virgin and a maiden, it is highly unlikely that Laban was her younger brother. Admittedly, this evidence does not constitute proof that is set in stone.